# Ayuda con ejercicio de Listas, Python

Tags: lista

que tal? me podrian ayudar con este ejercicio? no creo que sea muy dificil pero no lo saco.

### Desarrollar una función que devuelva en un vector (una lista) los números primos
entre 2 y 200.

```
lista = []



def esPrimo ():
    confirm = True
    contador = 2
    for i in range (2,201):
        contador += 1
        resto = contador%i
        if (resto != 0):
            confirm = False
        return confirm

        if confirm==True:
            lista.append(contador)

    return lista
            


def main():
    lista = esPrimo()
    print(lista)


    
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el código arreglado, te he puesto en comentarios todas las explicaciones necesarias:

```
def es_primo():  # En python los nombres de funciones y variables no suelen llevar mayúsculas, se usa snake_case
    lista = []  # Mejor declararla dentro del método
    for i in range(2, 201):
        confirm = True  # Siempre reseteamos confirm a True, vamos a asumir que siempre son primos a no ser
        # que encontremos un divisor
        for num in range(2, i):  # Te faltaba este segundo bucle for completamente. No basta con comprobar el número
            # con otro... hay que comprobar CADA número desde el 2 hasta el número actual para ver si alguno es divisor
            resto = i % num
            if resto == 0:  # Esto lo tenías mal... un número es divisor de otro si el resultado es 0, no != 0
                confirm = False
                # Por aquí también tenías un return... el return rompe la ejecución de la función y devolvía false!
                break  # Si hemos encontrado un divisor break nos saca del bucle para ahorrar repeticiones
                # ya que ya sabemos que el número no será primo no tiene sentido comprobar los demás divisores
        if confirm:  # No hace falta comparar los booleans, si confirm es True esto entra directamente
            lista.append(i)
    return lista


def main():
    lista = es_primo()
    print(lista)


main()
```

Si tienes alguna otra duda pregunta!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Ayudar siempre es un placer, pero aquí no estamos para trabajar por otros. Fíjate en los cambios, lee los comentarios, intenta comprender lo que estaba mal. Si necesitas más ayuda siempre estamos aquí dispuestos, pero si no aprendemos de nuestros errores, los seguiremos cometiendo :)